# Improvement for std::map <int, run_some_function> double dispatch

Tags: c++

I am trying to do my c++ homework and as a part of it I have to implement a `std::map` with an `int` as its `key` and a `value` should be a specific `void` function, which prints some text.
I can`t find an answer to what are the correct ways of doing that.

This is what I have so far:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class testClass
{
public:
    void testFunc1() { std::cout << "func1\n"; }
    void testFunc2() { std::cout << "func2\n"; }
};

typedef void(testClass::*runFunc)(void);
typedef std::map<int, runFunc> myMapType;

int main() {
    testClass t1;

    std::map<int, runFunc> myMap;
    myMap.emplace(1, &testClass::testFunc1);
    myMap.emplace(2, &testClass::testFunc2);

    myMapType::const_iterator itr;
    itr = myMap.find(2);

    if (itr != myMap.end()) {
        (t1.*(itr->second))();
    }
}
```

The code is working now, however I am not sure if that is the way people with more experience do.

Also, if you are aware of any sources where one can read more about knowledge required to achieve the needed result - any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: If your code is a simplified version of what you really have to do, then it's off-topic and this question needs to be closed; per https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic - "In order to give good advice, we need to see real, concrete code, and understand the context in which the code is used. Generic code (such as code containing placeholders like foo, MyClass, or doSomething()) leaves too much to the imagination."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As other answers have already said, the trick you're looking for is called [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function), and it's defined in the standard `<functional>` header.

You include `<string>` but never use it. You define `myMapType` but never use it.

Unless you need portability back to C++03, you should use `using X = Y;` in place of `typedef Y X;`.

A common name for "scratch" iterator variables is `it` (not to be confused with `i` for integer indices). Your `itr` is reasonably clear, but not idiomatic.

---

Following the dictum that "good C++ code should look like Python," I'd write your program like this:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <functional>
#include <map>

void testFunc1() {
    puts("func1");
}    
void testFunc2() {
    puts("func2");
}

using MapType = std::map<int, std::function<void()>>;

int main() {
    MapType myMap = {
        { 1, testFunc1 },
        { 2, testFunc2 },
    };

    auto it = myMap.find(2);
    if (it != myMap.end()) {
        it->second();
    }
}
```

---

Instead of the map initializer I wrote, you could write

```
MapType myMap;
myMap[1] = testFunc1;
myMap[2] = testFunc2;
```

but I strongly recommend "declarative" over "imperative." "Declarative" style means to define the whole map at once, as a data object, in the state you want it; "imperative" style means to define an empty map and then repeatedly mutate it so as to *eventually arrive at* the state you want. "Declarative" tends to be easier to reason about.

Comment: I could do the benchmarking myself, but does anyone know already if there is any overhead to using `std::function<>` rather than function pointers here? Also, is there any benefit to creating a map entry with a lambda `[](){ testFunc(); }` rather than with the function name directly?

Answer (score 5):

In general your code looks good. But I have some little annotations (improvements) for you.

#### 1. I'd prefer direct initialization of `itr` for sake of readability:

```
myMapType::const_iterator itr = myMap.find(2);
```

instead of

```
myMapType::const_iterator itr;
itr = myMap.find(2);
```

That said you could also avoid

```
typedef std::map<int, runFunc> myMapType;
```

completely using the `auto` keyword:

```
auto itr = myMap.find(2);
```

#### 2. Make use `std::function` and lambda bindings

For the callable value parameter of the `std::map` I'd prefer to use an appropriate [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) value type and [*lambda function bindings*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) to the instance to operate on.

```
testClass t1;

std::map<int, std::function<void()>> myMap;
myMap.emplace(1, [&t1](){t1.testFunc1();});
myMap.emplace(2, [&t1](){t1.testFunc2();});
```

This will give you greater flexibility for later changes and use of other classes than just `testClass`. Also you can get rid of that other type definition then:

```
typedef void(testClass::*runFunc)(void);
```

As soon you want to use your map for the general case you can clearly see the benefits:

```
class A {
public:
     void print() { std::cout << "print() from class A.\n"; }
};

class B {
public:
     void print() { std::cout << "print() from class B.\n"; }
};

// ...
int main() {
    A a;
    B b;

    std::map<int, std::function<void()>> myMap;
    myMap.emplace(1, [&a](){a.print();});
    myMap.emplace(2, [&b](){b.print();});

}
```

---

Here's my set of changes in whole (you can check it's still working as intended [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ddc6f12661f9f89b)):

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

class testClass
{
public:
    void testFunc1() { std::cout << "func1\n"; }
    void testFunc2() { std::cout << "func2\n"; }
};

int main() {
    testClass t1;

    std::map<int, std::function<void()>> myMap;
    myMap.emplace(1, [&t1](){t1.testFunc1();});
    myMap.emplace(2, [&t1](){t1.testFunc2();});

    auto itr = myMap.find(2);

    if (itr != myMap.end()) {
        (itr->second)();
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of a lambda that calls the function you can use [std::bind](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind).

Comment: @EmilyL. But lambdas are preferred over `std::bind`! There is no need for it now. Lambdas are far more expressive.

Comment: @lightnessracesinorbit that's the first I've heard, can you give a reference? I still feel like bind is better expressing the intent

Comment: @EmilyL. Sure! https://stackoverflow.com/a/17545183/560648

Answer (score 0):

Given your current test code, there's no reason for `testClass` to exist. Your two test functions can simply be functions in the global namespace, and then your `emplace` calls can be simplified.

```
void testFunc1() { std::cout << "func1\n"; }
void testFunc2() { std::cout << "func2\n"; }

typedef void(*runFunc)(void);
// ...

myMap.emplace(1, testFunc1);
myMap.emplace(2, testFunc2);
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. my code above is a simplified version of what I really have to do. with just global functions it won't go.

Comment: See comments on question, in that case. This is off-topic.